# Increasing kernel memory size

Tags: linux, kernel, memory, embedded

I have an embedded board with 512MB of RAM running Linux 2.6.29 and UBoot bootloader. But the kernel is able to utilize only 128MB of RAM.

I tried changing the value of `XCODE_MEMSIZE`, which I think determines how much RAM the kernel uses.

When I set it to 512, the kernel crashes while booting up. Is there any other configuration parameter that needs to be changed?

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding the crash you mention? What do you see on screen? Any errors?

Comment: And what board is it?

Comment: Really need to provide more details about 'only able to use 128MB'.  It sounds like something has been limited somewhere (stack size per user, etc).

Comment: how much memory is u-boot detecting? Does it detect the whole of 512MB?

Comment: What does `cat /proc/cmdline` tell you on your board?

Answer (score 3):

Without more specific knowledge of your embedded board two things come to mind.

1. Try kernel `mem=` boot parameter. (I think sometimes the memory might be available from non-continous address so you might have to use something like this, but the addresses will be have to be checked per you mobo.

   mem=512M@0 mem=256M@0x80000000 mem=256M=0xc0000000
2. Do you have embedded graphics card? That might take out a chunk of your available ram. If you can get to the bios or equivalent, check that.

@see [Kernel paramters](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt) for more information on `mem=`

Comment: You may need to specify a value less than 512M - perhaps there's a device or something at or near physical address 0x20000000 (512M) in the board's memory map, which, you should get a copy of to know where the RAM lives on your board.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should increase `RAM Disk` size in your kernel.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the other posts about being more specific, I would also suggest unmounting `/dev/shm` if it is mounted. That is a ramdisk filesystem and eats into your ram.

Also take a look at the `sysctl` command in linux. Doing something like `sysctl -w kernel.shmmax="<some number>"` changes the kernel while it's running.

Comment: /dev/shm uses barely any memory if its empty. It will only start using ram once files are loaded into it.

Comment: /dev/shm is nothing but implementation of traditional shared memory concept. It is an efficient means of passing data between programs. One program will create a memory portion, which other processes (if permitted) can access. This will result into speeding up things on Linux.